# Docker: writing a file to physical or shared path, using docker and netcore3.1

Tags: c#, docker, file, containers

what I'm trying to do is simply write files to a path

```
private string CreateIfMissing(string path)
    {
        path = Path.Combine(_options.baseBath, path);

        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

        return path;
    }
```

Suppose my storage base path is  `D:\STORAGE_ROOT`

it works fine until I run it using a docker container, it results to create the full path again inside my app folder.

`C:\App\MyRunningAppFolder\D*\STORAGE_ROOT\path_value`.

Is there a way to enable or force the directory to point on the sent path, not the app path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first solution that comes to my mind is to **volume mount your external directory** (storage base path) **to an internal directory in your container**.

Then, you can create the directories in that internal directory, and these directories will also be created in your storage base path.

The code will then need to use this internal directory as `path`.

[Docker Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)

Comment: you say, the `volume mount` will create a sync between the (storage base path) and internal directory inside my container?

Comment: which means any change on the storage will be synced with the internal path and reverse

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried it before, but maybe you can share a folder on network so you can access it from inside Docker as something like this //{YouMachineIP}/C$/MyProject/SharedFolder